# Finding most efficient method for large switch-case and if-else

Tags: c++, switch-statement, polymorphism

I'm learning OOP and I found that you can use polymophism to replace switch-case and if-else. But I still wonder how to do that most efficiently. Here is my manage class for managing info of 5 different class:

```cpp
class Manage
{
private:
    Human *List[100];
    int iObject_num;
public:
    Manage(){
        iObject_num=0;
    }
    ~Manage(){
        delete List;
    }
    void vInList()
    {
        int choice;
            do
                {
                    Menu(); //the menu has 6 choices
                    fflush(stdin);
                    cin>>choice;
                    switch(choice)
                    {
                    case 1:{
                        List[iObject_num]= new Student;
                        List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate(); // input the protected info of base class
                        List[iObject_num]->vIn();// input the private of each child class
                        iObject_num++;
                        break;}
                    case 2:{
                        List[iObject_num]= new Undergrad;
                        List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();
                        List[iObject_num]->vIn();
                        iObject_num++;
                        break;}
                    case 3:{
                        List[iObject_num]= new Worker;
                        List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();
                        List[iObject_num]->vIn();
                        iObject_num++;
                        break;}
                    case 4:{
                        List[iObject_num]= new Actor;
                        List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();
                        List[iObject_num]->vIn();
                        iObject_num++;
                        break;}
                    case 5:{
                        List[iObject_num]= new Musician;
                        List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();
                        List[iObject_num]->vIn();
                        iObject_num++;
                        break;}
                    case 0:
                        cout<<"Exiting...\n";
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout<<"Invalid!\n";
                    }
                } while(choice!=0);

    };
    void vOutList(){
        cout<<"Total number of input: "<<iObject_num<<"\n";
        for (int i=0;i<iObject_num;i++)
        {
            List[i]->vOutPrivate();
            List[i]->vOut();
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
};
```

I've been searching for answer but most of them all told the same thing: override the virtual function. I've already do that as you can see, but if there's more than 5 classes, I will have to do switch-case more than 5 times to call each class' function?

Comment: just move `List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();List[iObject_num]->vIn();iObject_num++;` after the switch statement?

Comment: That's not so big, just make functions for the cases and call them instead.

Comment: Looking at this I think the better approach would be smarter constructors for the classes derived from `Human`. You could get the duplication down to the `iObject_num++;` because the constructors would do everything else.

Comment: Side note: You flush output, not input. The behaviour of `fflush(stdin);` is undefined. That doesn't mean that on a given target you won't get exactly the behaviour you want, one of the beauties of undefined behaviour is the implementation can do anything it wats including exactly what you want, but you get absolutely no guarantees from the language.

Comment: Side note: You can't simply move the virtual functions after the switch. Because the switch can exit without assigning a new object in the failure cases. You'll have to be slightly smarter.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but what is the purpose of the `fflush(stdin)`? It looks like `Menu()` displays options; after it returns, the code reads from `stdin`? If that's the case, keep in mind that `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied together, so reading from `std::cin` first flushes `std::cout`. There's hardly ever any need to manually synchronize them.

Comment: You could use a table (array) of pointers to functions.  The functions would handle the appropriate response.  If your selections are contiguous, you could use the array.  However, using a structure entry of `{selection_id, pointer_to_function}` would be safer, because then you can search for the selection regardless of the order of the entries in the table.

Comment: You will always need some sort of enumeration of the classes and a way to dispatch to the desired factory. Hence, you can't remove the `switch` or an equivalent mechanism, but you can make each `case` smaller as @AlanBirtles explains.

Answer (score 1):

You can create factory for example HumanFactory

```
class HumanFactory
{
public:
    virtual Human* createHuman() = 0;
    virtual ~HumanFactory() {}
};

class StudentFactory : public HumanFactory
{
public:
    Human* createHuman() override { return new Student; }
};
```

and all the concrete humans can be added to list in

```
class Manage
{
private:
    std::vector<Human*> humans;
    std::vector<HumanFactory*> factories;
    
// register factory 
void registerFactory(HumanFactory* factory)
    {
        factories.push_back(factory);
    }

void vInList()
    {
        int choice;
        do
        {
            Menu(); // The menu has 6 choices
            std::cin >> choice;

            if (choice >= 1 && choice <= factories.size())
            {
                Human* human = factories[choice - 1]->createHuman();
                human->vInPrivate();
                human->vIn();
                humans.push_back(human);
            }
            else if (choice != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid choice!\n";
            }
        } while (choice != 0);
    }

int main()
{
    Manage manager;
    manager.registerFactory(new StudentFactory());
    // Register other factories as needed

    manager.vInList();
    manager.vOutList();

    return 0;
}
```

I have provided code, not fully finished but I think will give you idea how to replace switch.

Comment: Added more code, see above. Factory is a vector so you can access factory with index.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to avoid switch-case, you can use the following approach:

```
template <typename T, int x>
struct IndexedHumanType {
};

using AllIndexedHumanTypes = std::tuple<
  IndexedHumanType<Student, 1>,
  IndexedHumanType<Undergrad, 2>,
  IndexedHumanType<Worker, 3>,
  IndexedHumanType<Actor, 4>,
  IndexedHumanType<Musician, 5>
>;

class Manage {
private:
  template <typename T, int I, typename... Others>
  bool handle(int choice, std::tuple<IndexedHumanType<T, I>, Others...>) {
    if (choice == I) {
      List[iObject_num] = new T;
      List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate();
      List[iObject_num]->vIn();
      ++iObject_num;
      return true;
    }
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Others) == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return handle(choice, std::tuple<Others...>{});
    }
  }
  
  bool handle(int choice) {
    return handle(choice, AllIndexedHumanTypes{});
  }
...
};
```

This is static polymorphism. If you have multiple places with switch-case sequences, you can generalize `handle` to accept a lambda function, accepting, in turn, `IndexedHumanType`, and performing whatever work is necessary.

However, the most efficient in terms of runtime solution *is* switch-case.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I prefer to define a map that uses your type as the key and a function (lambda or otherwise) that handles the specific work needed for that type. To pseudocode it:

```
std::map<int, funct> type_map;

type_map[1] = [*this]() {                         
                            List[iObject_num]= new Student;
                            List[iObject_num]->vInPrivate(); // input the protected info of base class
                            List[iObject_num]->vIn();// input the private of each child class
                            iObject_num++;
}
```

Then range check your input (is it in the map), and if so, execute the method.

Comment: Great idea. Note that for a 1 to 6 choice matrix, `std::map`s is a bit overkill-y. A simple array or `std::array` of `std::function`s will do the same thing with far less hidden overhead. If there the options are not sequential or the options are input as strings, `map` rules. But for what the asker describes, `std::array<funct> type_map;` is simple and sweet and accessible as `type_map[choice]();`.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree with you completely. The reason I first fell into this pattern was due to a need to map several hundred strings to something else.